# C# Threading UI for wait dialog

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, progressdialog

Ok. I have looked around some tried to thread my UI to make this work.

I have an application for reporting information. How this work is that I a user control that can be repeated in a scrollable area. so If there are 10 reports to load for a day, it will load this control 20 times in the scrollable area.

What I would like is to make a "Please wait" dialog while loading theese controls. But there seems to be a problem to thread UI as a progressbar in Marquee mode wont animate while drawing these controls that should lie in the scrollable area behind.

Have tried to generate the controls in a backgroundworker but that wont solve the problem when it comes to the progressbar.

Any ideas or tips when it come to threading UI drawing? 
As I suppose this is what it is. progressbar while drawing other controls.

EDIT:
I tried show this "Please wait" dialog as both `Show();` and `ShowDialog();`. ShowDialog() works but only becouse it pauses the rest of the applications as it waits for an answer.

Here is the peace of code generating the controls. this is not the threaded version for background. but the only diffrence is where the "pleaseWait" dialog is placed in the code.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Generates assignemts after date
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date">Date for selection of what to show</param>
    /// <param name="currentWeek">Week to show</param>
    /// <param name="igonerWeekCheck">Ignor week check, used for startup</param>
    private void GenerateAssigmentsAfterDate(DateTime date, int currentWeek, bool igonerWeekCheck)
    {
        //refresh UI before generating contens
        tabPage1.Refresh();
        panelScroller.Refresh();
        splitContainer1.Refresh();

        //freezes UI while loading
        SuspendDrawing(splitContainer1);
        panelScroller.SuspendLayout();

        if (CurrentTMEngine.LatestWeekNumber != GetWeekNumber(date) || igonerWeekCheck == true)
        {
            if (igonerWeekCheck == false)
            {
                pleaseWait = PleaseWaitDialog();
                pleaseWait.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                pleaseWait.Show();
                pleaseWait.Update();
            }

            //should remove current controls from memory
            int ctrlCount = panelScroller.Controls.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < ctrlCount; i++)
            {
                panelScroller.Controls[0].Dispose();
            }

            panelScroller.Refresh();

            assignmentList.Clear();
            assignmentList = null;
            assignmentList = new List<messageCtrl>();

            int rowCountCtrl = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in CurrentTMEngine.TMassignmentsTable.Rows)
            {
                if (currentWeek == GetWeekNumber(Convert.ToDateTime(row[new TableText().TimeStart]).Date))
                {
                    messageCtrl repCtrl = new messageCtrl(rowCountCtrl, Convert.ToInt32(row[new TableText().ID]),
                        Convert.ToDateTime(row[new TableText().TimeStart]), Convert.ToDateTime(row[new TableText().TimeEnd]),
                        panelScroller.Controls, CurrentTMEngine.TMassignmentsTable, row, CurrentTMEngine);
                    assignmentList.Add(repCtrl);//collection to be avalie for show
                    rowCountCtrl++;
                }
            }
            foreach (messageCtrl assign in assignmentList)
            {
                if (currentWeek == GetWeekNumber(assign.StartTime.Date))
                {
                    if (assign.StartTime.Date == date)
                    {
                        assign.Enabled = true;
                        assign.Height = 142;
                        assign.tableLayoutPanel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        assign.Enabled = false;
                        assign.Height = 5;
                        assign.tableLayoutPanel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
                    }
                    panelScroller.Controls.Add(assign); //ands control
                }
            }
            // SetSizeMessageCtrlByDate(date, currentWeek);


            pleaseWait.Close();
            pleaseWait.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            SetSizeMessageCtrlByDate(date, currentWeek);
        }
        CurrentTMEngine.LatestWeekNumber = GetWeekNumber(date);

        //unfrezzing UI
        panelScroller.ResumeLayout();
        ResumeDrawing(splitContainer1);
    }
    #endregion
```

EIDT 2: 
Seems to be related to the rendering/drawing of the UI components. I can see this as I expand this scrollable area for the controllers so they all fit. The application freezes until the UI has been redrawn to be with out scrollbar. And vise versa for making it smaller for scroll. 
This seems to be the type of freeze that occurs while loading the controls. So I guess unless there is a way to have multiple UI threads it might be hard to find a solution for this as it is located in the same application and this applications UI thread.

Solution for the problem right now is a "Please wait" dialog without a animated Marquee scrollbar.

Will check in to if there is a way to create a separate application for this to fill this purse as that seems to be the only solution.

Comment: Your problem might be that each control does it's underlying work on the UI thread - do the controls load their own data, and is this done on the UI thread ?

Comment: It's very difficult to diagnose this without seeing your code.  Obviously your code is doing something to hog the UI thread.  You need to find out what that is and move it to a background thread.

Comment: there are some data being loaded in each of these generated controls. But as I said, I tried generating and apply these controls from a backgroundworker. should not this data being loaded be handled by the backgroundworker? Or dose it get UI anyway because the controls are invoked to the UI thead?

Comment: How complex are the controls?  It's possible the delay is not caused by gathering the data, but rather the actual construction and rendering of the control itself (which always occurs on the UI thread).  This is a common problem when instantiating multiple instances of complex UserControls in WinForms.  I recommend adding some tracing code using a Stopwatch to benchmark what part of your code is taking the most time.  Alternately, use a performance profiling tool (there are quite a few good commercial offerings.)

Comment: Not that complex but we are not talking grid rows and cell here :) . So rendering could very well be an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have access to the source code for the controls? It sounds like the controls are using the UI thread to do some kind of background process (causing the delay). Unfortunately there is only one UI thread, so if it is tied up, you get a stalling effect.

If you have access to the code you could change it to asynchronously load avoiding this issue. If you don't have access the only solution that I can think of would be to launch another process which would have a separate UI thread (I think), however that would requiring creating a message box style window.

Comment: @Jonas Lindahi - I am pretty sure UI threads aren't shared across application boundaries. However this involves running a separate application to take advantage of that fact.